# Targeting Specific Resolution CSS Media Query

Tags: css, media-queries, screen-resolution

I have a crazy web app going on, with all kinds of dynamic widths and heights and vertically centered stuff.  It looks great on just about every resolution except 1366x768 and 1280x800.  I know how to fix it with some CSS rule overrides.  I want to target these SPECIFIC resolutions ONLY (meaning I do NOT want to target 1280x1024 with a min-width: 1280 and max-width: 1280).  Please don't lecture me about best practices and stuff, I need a quick and dirty answer.

How can I do this?  Surprisingly Google isn't giving me any good results.

Answer (score 7):

You could use:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1280px)
              and (min-height: 800px) and (max-height: 800px) {
    /* Crazy CSS overrides here */
}
/* Second variant left as an exercise for the reader */
```

However, you will probably do better in the long run if you take the time to refactor now - later never seems to get here.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried, but it doesn't work for some reason.  It's even my last CSS rule in my stylesheet, and I threw in an !important for good measure.

Comment: Apparently min-height applies to the windows innerHeight, not the height value of your resolution.  So, with tabs, address bar, status bar, toolbars, etc, I ended up going with min-height: 680px and max-height: 800px.  Thanks for the direction, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 800px)
{
/*write CSS here*/
}
```

Comment: hi sir I am facing one issue my senior's screen is 1366x768 because of that they are getting lot of whitespaces but from my side I removed all the spaces how can I target this specific size in media query